# How can we implement security for agent pools in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

How can we restrict access to agent pools for certain groups in azure devops. As of now everyone has the access to agent pool . I need to manage that access. Any one please help

Comment: Please review this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser

Comment: IS this the same with self hosted agents

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure DevOps agent pool, We can configure different permissions by updating user roles. Such as configure the agent permissions to restrict user or group access the agent pool.

Steps:

Open org setting-> agent pools->select agent pool->click the tab Security->remove the user or permission group

Result: the user or group member cannot access the agent pool.

[image]

Please refer the doc [Security of agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#security) and [About security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops) for more details.